# Why Can't I Translate JS Canvas Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I know you can translate images using `ctx.translate()` but when I do it, it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong. I spent a solid 2 hours trying to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="tank_layer" height="1080" width="1920"></canvas>

var canvas = document.getElementById('tank_layer'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

document.onkeydown=function(){

  ctx.translate(100,150)
}
img = new Image(1920, 1080),
img.src="../tanks/maps/2.png"

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to redraw the image after translation. Add `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` inside your onkeydown function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redraw your image after translation so add the following:

```
document.onkeydown=function(){ 
    ctx.translate(100,150) 
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0)
}
```

**idea**

```
var counter=0;

document.onkeydown=function(){ 
    if (counter===0) {
        ctx.translate(100,150);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it translates. But it loops and moves the image 100 pixels every time I press a key. I just want it to move to those coordinates once.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is add a counter/boolean and an if inside the function to only move if false or counter=0

Comment: Will redrawing the image slow down my page? I'm working with a fairly large image.
Is there away around having to redraw?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with drawing the image then translating it and drawing it again? Why not draw it at the translated position at the beginning?

Comment: I'm making a 2d scroller game.

Comment: Okay. Still doesn't really answer why you want to translate it once on keydown. It shouldn't slow down the page too much though..